# Transfer file using Sockets Server/Client

Tags: java, android

Hi there I have 2 classes in order to push a file into an android device.

My Server CLass:

```
    public class FileServer {
      public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {
        // create socket
        ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(13267);
        while (true) {
          System.out.println("Waiting...");

          Socket sock = servsock.accept();
          System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);

          // sendfile
          File myFile = new File ("C:\\Users\\Petrica\\Desktop\\zzz.txt");
          byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
          BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
          bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
          OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
          System.out.println("Sending...");
          os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
          os.flush();
          sock.close();
          }
        }
    }

And my Client Class:

public class TCPClient extends AsyncTask{
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
    int filesize=6022386; // filesize temporary hardcoded

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int bytesRead;
    int current = 0;
    // localhost for testing
    Socket sock = null;
    try {
        sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1",13267);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Connecting...");

    // receive file
    try {
    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/zzz.txt");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);


    current = bytesRead;

    // thanks to A. Cádiz for the bug fix
    do {
       bytesRead =
          is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
       if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
    } while(bytesRead > -1);

    bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
    bos.flush();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end-start);
    bos.close();
    sock.close();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    return null;
}
}
```

I get an error

```
    09-09 15:52:39.261: E/AndroidRuntime(802): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-09 15:52:39.261: E/AndroidRuntime(802): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-09 15:52:39.261: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-09 15:52:39.261: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
09-09 15:52:39.261: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
09-09 15:52:39.261: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
09-09 15:52:39.261: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-09 15:52:39.261: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-09 15:52:39.261: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-09 15:52:39.261: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-09 15:52:39.261: E/AndroidRuntime(802): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 15:52:39.261: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at com.aaaaaa.TCPClient.doInBackground(TCPClient.java:33)
09-09 15:52:39.261: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at com.aaaaaa.TCPClient.doInBackground(TCPClient.java:1)
09-09 15:52:39.261: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-09 15:52:39.261: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-09 15:52:39.261: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  ... 4 more
```

MainActivity:

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TCPClient tcpc;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tcpc.execute();
                }
            });
        }


}
```

Does anyone have an idea what should I do ??? In the future i would like to send 2 files :D .Thanks in advice .

Comment: First of all, check your Activity, because it's throwing a null pointer exception.

Comment: in my activity i have a button , that on click executes my doinbackground method.

Comment: What happens on line 15 of the activity, during onCreate()?  Maybe you could include onCreate?

Comment: Could you upload the whole java file of Server Class?

Comment: Do you initialize your button correctly before setting an onClickListener? Proper sequence is:
1. setContentView
2. findViewById
3. Check if returned view is null
4. setOnClickListener

Comment: I added the MainActivity class

Comment: @AndrasBalázsLajtha I've forgotten  my setContentView . I  got other Exceptions, i've edited my post

Comment: Should initialize tcpc with a value like tcpc = new TCPClient ();

Comming from C++, are you?

Comment: Well , i started with pascal :)) than C++ , now im new in java. But i don t have experience...

Comment: I've edited my log cat  geting other erros:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really expected to be able to sort out your own `NullPointerExceptions:` at least I expect it, but when you get past that, your copy code is wrong. You are presently ignoring the count returned by `read()` and assuming it fills the buffer. It isn't guaranteed to do that. See the Javadoc.

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
   out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Use this at both ends, with any buffer size > 0, typically 8192.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your Socket is connecting, but its hard to tell.  IN your log output, it says NullPointerException caused by doInBackground() line 33.  You should check line 33 in your editor, and better yet, show us in your post which line is 33.  I kind of have a feeling that you call Socket sock = null;, then you try and instantiate a new Socket in a try block, but that fails, so sock still == null, then you call a method on sock, and boom, NPE.

If you are running the Server on a computer, and the AsyncTask on an Android device, you won't be able to try and connect to localhost (127.0.0.1).  You should instead try to connect to the internal network ip of your computer (something like 192.168.1.XXX), assuming both devices are on WiFi.  If you are running an android emulator, then 127.0.0.1 refers back to the emulated device, and all emulator sessions run on an emulated router that you will have to configure for port forwarding before you can refer to the development machine, see here-->http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

As Andras Balazs Lajtha says, it looks like TCPClient isn't ever initialized/created during onCreate(), it is only declared.  Since your logcat output shows errors from TCPClient though, I assume you have that code actually running.

In general, when you post a log output that refers to problems with a specific line of code, you should start there, and when you post, tell us or show us which line that is.  And of course, if line 33 isn't related to a null Socket object, then I haven't been much help at all :)